# Use two different regex expressions to replace text in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, obfuscation

I'm trying to achieve with the below script to find an Amex credit card and a Visa card in each file and replace the main part of the PAN with stars only leaving 4 on each end. Now that works however I get a weird result with the below script, rather than just replacing part of the VISA card number it adds a copy of that line with the replacement. Then when the script runs the next If statement for the Amex obfuscation it works as It should.

Does anyone know where i'm going wrong with my logic? Would be very much appreciated.

```
$Enhanced_TRXReports = Get-ChildItem $TRXDestinationFilePath -include "Payment.txt","InvoiceHeader.txt" -File -Recurse

foreach ($Enhanced_TRXReport in $Enhanced_TRXReports){
$ReportPath = $Enhanced_TRXReport.FullName
$ReportName = $Enhanced_TRXReport.Name
$content = (Get-content $ReportPath) | ForEach {
    if($_ -match ",4[0-9]{15},"){
    $matched = $Matches[0]
    $String = $_
    $firsthalf = $matched.Substring(1,4)
    $secondhalf = $matched.Substring(13,4)
    $final = "," + $firsthalf + '********' + $secondhalf + ","
    [regex]$regex = ",4[0-9]{15},"
    $String -replace $regex,$final 
    }
    if($_ -match ",3[0-9]{14},"){
    $matched = $Matches[0]
    $String = $_
    $firsthalf = $matched.Substring(1,4)
    $secondhalf = $matched.Substring(12,4)
    $final = "," + $firsthalf + '*******' + $secondhalf + ","
    [regex]$regex = ",3[0-9]{14},"
    $String -replace $regex,$final 
}
    else
    {
        $_
    }
    }
Set-Content -Path $ReportPath -Value $content
}
```

Comment: If it's comma-separated, why don't you split them, process what you need to, then re-join them?

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and an example input file. Also post an example of what output you were expecting, and how specifically your code isn't working.

Comment: The reason for your error is using `if()` on one line and `if () { } else { }` for the other so you could actually end up with wrong or missing replacements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the reason my script wasn't working is because for the second `if` statement I didn't use `else if`. Once I used `else if` the script worked as expected. TheIncorrigible1 was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure regex, here's a slightly easier way to handle it where you won't end up with double-processing (mostly due to the switch statement being an explicit break).  I made the assumption that the lines could have non-card numbers on them, and although I didn't case for it, I'm assuming this is actually a CSV.  Also, [according to this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html), amex can be 34 or 37, so I've updated for that case.

```
#Requires -Version 4

(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include payment.txt,invoiceheader.txt -File -Recurse).ForEach({
    (Get-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName).ForEach({
        ($PSItem -split ',').ForEach({
            switch -Regex ($PSItem) {
                '4\d{15}' {
                    $PSItem -replace '(\d{4})\d{8}(\d{4})', '$1********$2'
                }
                '3[47]\d{13}' {
                    $PSItem -replace '(\d{4})\d{7}(\d{4})', '$1*******$2'
                }
                default {
                    $PSItem
                }
            }
        }) -join ','
    }) | Set-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName
})
```